eBay REST API getOrders returning an empty array
I have successfully authenticated my application, created an access token through Oauth and refreshed it without any issues. I now need to be able to request orders for fulfilment. I have the correct scope (https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.fulfillment) and I can make the API call to https://api.ebay.com/sell/fulfillment/v1/order without any issue, no error - everything seems to be working perfectly. But when I make the call on my test eBay account which has one order, the orders array is returned empty.
I thought maybe it takes time to process, but it has been over 18 hours now and still, the orders array is empty.
I am not getting any errors, so I don't understand why it's not returning orders.
I have run the API call from both my Laravel application and through Postman, both give the same results, empty orders array.
Does anyone have any ideas or solutions?
